# Bug in a fixed If - Else statement

Tags: c++, if-statement

this is my first post in this site.

As the title says, I encountered a bug in an If - else if - else block of codes.
What the problem is that, I am pretty confident that I have covered all 9 possible outcomes that there should be.

It is quite hard to explain more, so if you guys could take a look at my .cpp file and run it ( hopefully it runs because I used **c++ on a mac**), you may find an easier understanding of my problem.

[source code cpp file](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=85276649368331619649)

If you browse through my **action();**, in the else statement, I purposely displayed that you encountered a bug so just in case there were bugs, I'd be informed.

What I am trying to do is like this:

```
userinput | randomAImove | outcome

A             1           statement
A             2           statement
A             3           statement
D             1           statement
D             2           statement
D             3           statement
W             1           statement
W             2           statement
W             3           statement
else        1||2||3       statement
```

There are corresponding statements to each conditions met.
'A', 'W', 'D' are user input. I used a toupper command to force the compiler to just check on 'A' 'W' 'D'. However, the main problem I find is that, even if the toupper works(which I confirmed), the program displays the correct statement often but still somehow manages to bug even if the user(I tried it) input from A, W, D (not-case sensitive cuz of toupper).

Please just try it and after a few tries you may encounter it also. I wrote "you encountered a bug" if you ever do encounter it.

Please help me because I can't really see any other way to find the mistake. Maybe its in my plain sight but I can't seem to notice which one is it.

Thank you!

Comment: You need to reduce your code to a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and include it _in_ your post, not a link to it.

Answer (score -1):

Change the `AImove` function to

```
void AImove()

{
    turn = rand () % 3 + 1;

}
```

(add `+ 1`), or you may get `0` in `turn` and it will lead you "encounter a bug".

Comment: Hi! Thanks sir! I actually realized that 2 days ago but thank you anyway for confirming my mistake. Thank you again especially for taking time to check my problem.